# Custom records reader PST file format in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, pst, recordreader

I am  working on PST files, I have worked on writing custom record reader for a Mapreduce program for different input formats but this time it is going to be spark.

I am not getting any clue or documentation on implementing record readers in spark.
Can some body help on this? Is it possible to implement this functionality in spark?

Comment: Did you try using `sparkContext.hadoopRDD`?

Comment: We can use that but I am not sure about the corresponding hadoop file format that has to be extended for PST file format.